# Windows 2008 Server Manager cannot connect to Windows 2003 machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm trying to connect to Windows 2003 Server SP1 machine from Windows 2008 Server machine with Server Manager and getting following error:

[Window Title]
Server Manager

[Main Instruction]
Server Manager cannot connect to mtx-app-4.emea.int.genesyslab.com. Click Retry to try to connect again.

[Expanded Information]
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The resource URI (http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.ServerManager) was not found in the WS-Management catalog. The catalog contains the metadata that describes resources, or logical endpoints. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

[^] Hide details  [Retry] [Cancel]

Please advice how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/q-can-server-manager-manage-windows-server-2003-boxes) Server 2008 RTM Server Manager is not capable of doing remote management, 2008 R2 can do it but doesn't support management of Server 2003.

And TN article "[Remote Management with Server Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759202.aspx)" states the same, quote:

> The following remote management scenarios are supported from Server
>   Manager in Windows Server 2008 R2:
>
> - Server to server   Server Manager on a full installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 can be used to manage roles and features that are
>     installed on another server that is running Windows Server 2008 R2.
> - Server to Server Core   Server Manager on a full installation of Windows Server 2008 R2 can be used to manage roles and features that
>     are installed on a Server Core installation of Windows Server 2008 R2.
> - Client to server   Server Manager is installed as part of Remote Server Administration Tools on a computer that is running Windows® 7.
>     This can be used to manage roles and features on a computer that is
>     running either the full or Server Core installations of Windows Server
>     2008 R2.

Comment: Yes, WinRM is enabled on my 2003 server

Answer (score 0):

Is WinRM installed/enabled on your 2003 server?

> WinRM is not installed by default, but it is available as the Hardware
>   Management feature through the Add/Remove System Components feature in
>   the Control Panel under Management and Monitoring Tools.

See here for more info:  [Installation and Configuration for Windows Remote Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can also verify/troubleshoot on the remote 2003 server (after RDPing into it) by running:

`winrm e winrm/config/listener`

and

`winrm get winrm/config`